# Regex gets more result then in text available

Tags: regex, perl

I have a really weird problem: i searching for URLs on a html site and want only a specific part of the url. In my test html page the link occurs only once, but instead of one result i get about 20...

this is my regex im using:

```
perl -ne 'm/http\:\/\myurl\.com\/somefile\.php.+\/afolder\/(.*)\.(rar|zip|tar|gz)/; print "$1.$2\n";'
```

sample input would be something like this:

```
<html><body><a href="http://myurl.com/somefile.php&x=foo?y=bla?z=sdf?path=/foo/bar/afolder/testfile.zip?more=arguments?and=evenmore">Somelinknme</a></body></html>
```

which is a very easy example. so in real the link would apper on a normal website with content around...

my result should be something like this:

```
testfile.zip
```

but instead i see this line very often... Is this a problem with the regex or with something else?

Comment: You should post sample input and output so that its easier to understand.

Comment: As daxim answered use a HTML parser to parse HTML. You can still use regexes on the results it produces and you will save yourself from a lot of parsing pain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the regex is [greedy](http://p3rl.org/retut#Matching-repetitions).

Use an appropriate tool for HTML instead: [HTML::LinkExtor](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aLinkExtor) or one of the [link methods in WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#LINK-METHODS), then [URI](http://p3rl.org/URI) to extract a specific part.

```
use 5.010;
use WWW::Mechanize qw();
use URI qw();
use URI::QueryParam qw();

my $w = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$w->get('file:///tmp/so10549258.html');
for my $link ($w->links) {
    my $u = URI->new($link->url);
    # 'http://myurl.com/somefile.php?x=foo&y=bla&z=sdf&path=/foo/bar/afolder/testfile.zip&more=arguments&and=evenmore'
    say $u->query_param('path');
    # '/foo/bar/afolder/testfile.zip'
    $u = URI->new($u->query_param('path'));
    say (($u->path_segments)[-1]);
    # 'testfile.zip'
}
```

Comment: mh seems quite good but my problem is that the pathlength and position of the filename varies on many points because the link is generated and many arguments are added, i added an example in my post!

Comment: Edited to fit your example data.

Comment: i think this solution is quite the best one, because its not that bruteforce as my first lines

Comment: i wouldn't particularly say this is best as it depends. If your only requirement is to fetch the path name, then parsing entire html file for that won't be termed as **best one**.

Comment: yes but i have to download it in all cases because it runs some javascript that first must be executed...

Answer (score 1):

Are there 20 lines following in the file after your link?

Your problem is that the matching variables are not reseted. You match your link the first time, `$1` and `$2` get their values. In the following lines the regex is not matching, but `$1` and `$2` has still the old values, **therefore you should print only if the regex matches** and not every time.

From [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), see section *Capture Groups*

> NOTE: Failed matches in Perl do not reset the match variables, which makes it easier to write code that tests for a series of more specific cases and remembers the best match.

Answer (score -2):

This should do the trick for your sample input & output.

```
$Str = '<html><body><a href="http://myurl.com/somefile.php&x=foo?y=bla?z=sdf?path=/foo/bar/afolder/testfile.zip?more=arguments?and=evenmore">Somelinknme</a></body></html>';

@Matches = ($Str =~ m#path=.+/(\w+\.\w+)#g);
print @Matches ;
```

Comment: If rating down, please post the reason for that. Its bad that you are being punished and not knowing reason for that!